# opengl different mouse coordinates in different screens

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I am trying to build a ball game where upon clicking only the red ball, changes color. Marble is the  function call to draw the ball.

```
#include<glut.h>
volatile GLint w1=GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN),h1=GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYSCREEN);//get screen dimensions

......
......
......

void firstrow(int flag)
{
float i;

for(i=-0.25;i<0.25;i+=0.10)
{
    count++;
    if(flag>1)
    c=medium();
    if(flag>2)
    c=difficult();
marble(i,0.4,-0.5, 0.06,0.12,0.12,c);
if(c==2)
{flag1[count]=count;}
Sleep(30);
}
}

void secondrow(int flag)
{
float i;
for(i=-0.25;i<0.25;i+=0.10)
{
    count++;
    c=2;
    if(flag>2)
    c=difficult1();
marble(i,0.1,-0.5, 0.06,0.12,0.12,c);
if(c==2)
    {flag1[count]=count;}
Sleep(30);
}
}

void thirdrow(int flag)
{
float i;
for(i=-0.25;i<0.25;i+=0.10)
{
    count++;
    if(flag>1)
    c=medium();
    if(flag>2)
    c=difficult();
marble(i,-0.2,-0.5, 0.06,0.12,0.12,c);
if(c==2)
    {flag1[count]=count;}
Sleep(30);
}
}

void fourthrow(int flag)
{
float i;
for(i=-0.25;i<0.25;i+=0.10)
{
    count++;
    c=2;
    /*if(flag>1)
    c=medium();*/
    if(flag>2)
    c=difficult1();
marble(i,-0.5,-0.5, 0.06,0.12,0.12,c);
if(c==2)
    {flag1[count]=count;}
Sleep(30);
}
}
```

now after printing 4 rows of ball. I am using the 2D coordinates of the mouse to detect the particular object.

```
void drawCircle(int x,int y)
{
/*--------- Target count and color change for 1st Row ------------*/
if(x>573 && x<626 && y>235 && y<291 && flag1[1]==1)
    {
        marble(-0.25,0.4,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        flag1[1]=0;
    }
if(x>655 && x<763 && y>235 && y<291 && flag1[2]==2)
    {
        marble(-0.15,0.4,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        flag1[2]=0;
    }
if(x>736 && x<785 && y>235 && y<291 && flag1[3]==3)
    {
        marble(-0.05,0.4,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        flag1[3]=0;
    }
if(x>815 && x<865 && y>235 && y<291 && flag1[4]==4)
    {
        marble(0.05,0.4,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        flag1[4]=0;
    }
if(x>896 && x<945 && y>235 && y<291 && flag1[5]==5)
    {
        marble(0.15,0.4,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        flag1[5]=0;
    }
if(x>976 && x<1025 && y>235 && y<291 && flag1[6]==6)
    {
        marble(0.25,0.4,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        flag1[6]=0;
    }

/*--------- Target count and color change for 2nd Row ------------*/
if(x>573 && x<626 && y>370 && y<423 && flag1[7]==7)
    {
        marble(-0.25,0.1,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        flag1[7]=0;
    }
if(x>655 && x<704 && y>370 && y<423 && flag1[8]==8)
    {
        marble(-0.15,0.1,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        flag1[8]=0;
    }
if(x>736 && x<785 && y>370 && y<423 && flag1[9]==9)
    {
        marble(-0.05,0.1,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        flag1[9]=0;
    }
if(x>815 && x<865 && y>370 && y<423 && flag1[10]==10)
    {
        marble(0.05,0.1,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        flag1[10]=0;
    }
if(x>896 && x<945 && y>370 && y<423 && flag1[11]==11)
    {
        marble(0.15,0.1,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        flag1[11]=0;
    }
if(x>976 && x<1025 && y>370 && y<423 && flag1[12]==12)
    {
        marble(0.25,0.1,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        flag1[12]=0;
    }

/*--------- Target count and color change for 3rd Row ------------*/
if(x>573 && x<626 && y>502 && y<556 && flag1[13]==13)
    {
        marble(-0.25,-0.2,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        flag1[13]=0;
    }
if(x>655 && x<763 && y>502 && y<556 && flag1[14]==14)
    {
        marble(-0.15,-0.2,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        flag1[14]=0;
    }
if(x>736 && x<785 && y>502 && y<556 && flag1[15]==15)
    {
        marble(-0.05,-0.2,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        flag1[15]=0;
    }
if(x>815 && x<865 && y>502 && y<556 && flag1[16]==16)
    {
        marble(0.05,-0.2,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        flag1[16]=0;
    }
if(x>896 && x<945 && y>502 && y<556 && flag1[17]==17)
    {
        marble(0.15,-0.2,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        flag1[17]=0;
    }
if(x>976 && x<1025 && y>502 && y<556 && flag1[18]==18)
    {
        marble(0.25,-0.2,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        flag1[18]=0;
    }

/*--------- Target count and color change for 4th Row ------------*/
if(x>573 && x<626 && y>635 && y<689 && flag1[19]==19)
    {
        marble(-0.25,-0.5,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        flag1[19]=0;
    }
if(x>655 && x<763 && y>635 && y<689 && flag1[20]==20)
    {
        marble(-0.15,-0.5,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        flag1[20]=0;
    }
if(x>736 && x<785 && y>635 && y<689 && flag1[21]==21)
    {
        marble(-0.05,-0.5,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        flag1[21]=0;
    }
if(x>815 && x<865 && y>635 && y<689 && flag1[22]==22)
    {
        marble(0.05,-0.5,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        flag1[22]=0;
    }
if(x>896 && x<945 && y>635 && y<689 && flag1[23]==23)
    {
        marble(0.15,-0.5,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        flag1[23]=0;
    }
if(x>976 && x<1025 && y>635 && y<689 && flag1[24]==24)
    {
        marble(0.25,-0.5,-0.6,0.06,0.12,0.12,0);
        targets++;
        //flag1[24]=0;
    }
cout<<targets<<endl;
cout<<x<<endl;
cout<<y<<endl;
glutIdleFunc(total);
}
```

If the program is run on different computers of different resolutions then the mouse coordinates for detecting the click varies in the draw circle.

flag1 stores the ball number with red color.

```
void mymouse(int button,int state,int x,int y){

    if(button==GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state==GLUT_DOWN)
        drawCircle(x,y);
}
```

"How Do I Make It Work Uniformly On Any System With Any Screen Size?"

Comment: Try converting 2D mouse coordinates to world 3d coordinates.But the screen dimensions are obtained dynamically, So It might differ for different screen sizes

Comment: Maybe divide mouse coordinates by screen size? Also, it's hard to read your code, so please indent it properly next time.

Comment: How to convert from 2d to 3d?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat .. Thank you very much.. I am new here so I will make sure I will indent it properly next time

Comment: Dividing by screen size doesn't help! I've tried that too!

Comment: my screen resolution is 1600x900... so w1=1600 & h1=900.       If i run the same program on a screen resolution of 1024x1280 then I wont get proper output!

Comment: @Akshay how to convert 2d to 3d